# Saving authorization response header from Postman script

Tags: postman

In Postman, the API I'm testing returns a Bearer token in the authorization header:

```
authorization: "Bearer eyJ0..."
```

I'm attempting to save the token value in an environment variable :

```
pm.test("Authorization token is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.header("authorization");
    
    // Save auth token to environment
    const tokenHeader = pm.response.headers.get("authorization")
    const parts = tokenHeader.split('Bearer')
    const token = parts[parts.length - 1]
    pm.environment.set("authToken", `${token}`);

    // testing: it prints eyJ0... as expected
    console.log(pm.environment.get("authToken"))
});
```

Trouble is, when I try to inject this value in other calls, instead of `eyJ0...`, I just get an ellipsis: "...".  If I hit the Environment Quick Look button (small eye near top right of UI), the value also shows as "...".  However, if I select it to try to edit, the true value of `eyJ0...` is shown.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Shoot I figured it out.  The problem was with my script.  I was splitting the string using the delimiter "Bearer"

```
const parts = tokenHeader.split('Bearer')
```

This meant that given input `Bearer eyJ0`, the array became `['Bearer', ' eyJ0']`. The space at the beginning of the token string was the problem.  I needed to modify the script to:

```
// Include the space in the delimiter (or just split on ' ')
const parts = tokenHeader.split('Bearer ')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that works perfect with a simple spring boot authentication

pm.globals.set("Authorization", pm.response.headers.get("Authorization"));